# PostgreSQL constraints for some fields

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I need all three fields in my table to be null at once, or all were not null. How to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a check constraint

```
alter table your_table
   add constraint check_nulls
   check (num_nonnulls(col1, col2, col3) in (0,3));
```

`num_nonnulls` counts the number of not-null values passed to it. Your requirement is that either all of them are null (result = 0) or all of them are not null (result = 3)